# put spinner in options menu

Tags: android, multilingual

How to create options menu that would select the languages below:
Languages: English, Chinese (Simplified) and Bahasa Malaysia

When English is selected the English values will be used 
When Chinese (Simplified) is selected the Chinese (Simplified)values will be used 
When Bahasa Malaysia is selected the Bahasa Malaysia Value will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the below tag in your layouts .xml file

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

Now you can define what your spinner must do, by implementing `onItemSelectedListener` Simple example is below:

```
package com.vimaltuts.android.spinner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView userSelection;
    private static final String[] items={"Android","Bluetooth","Chrome","Docs","Email",
        "Facebook","Google","Hungary","Iphone","Korea","Machintosh",
        "Nokia","Orkut","Picasa","Singapore","Turkey","Windows","Youtube"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        userSelection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_selection);
        Spinner my_spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
        my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        my_spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        userSelection.setText(items[pos]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userSelection.setText("");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!